# Is their a function to sort for data that happens in 3 consecutive years?

Tags: r, function, sorting, if-statement, filter

I have a data set that has several columns with one being Season. Id like to sort or filter the data that happened in 3 consecutive seasons per player(could be more or less, but starting with 3). Some players have played in 1 season and some up to 5 in a row.

```
pick224_structure <- structure( list( LEAGUE = c( "AJHL", "AJHL", "OHL", "OHL", "USHL", "USHL", "USHL", "NCAA", "AHL", "USHL", "QMJHL", "NCAA", "NCAA" ), NAME = c( "A.J. Belanger", "A.J. Belanger", "A.J. Cook", "A.J. Cook", "A.J. Drobot", "A.J. Drobot", "A.J. Fossen", "A.J. Fossen", "A.J. Greer", "A.J. Greer", "A.J. Greer", "A.J. Greer", "A.J. Greer" ), DY... = c( "DY+1", "DY", "DY-1", "DY", "DY+1", "DY+2", "DY+1", "DY+2", "DY+2", "DY-1", "DY+1", "DY", "DY+1" ), PLAYER.ID = c( "44972/a.j.-belanger", "44972/a.j.-belanger", "46065/a.j.-cook", "46065/a.j.-cook", "39426/a.j.-drobot", "39426/a.j.-drobot", "30211/a.j.-fossen", "30211/a.j.-fossen", "36537/a.j.-greer", "36537/a.j.-greer", "36537/a.j.-greer", "36537/a.j.-greer", "36537/a.j.-greer" ), POS = c("F", "F", "D", "D", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"), SEASON = c( 2020L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2017L, 2018L, 2013L, 2014L, 2017L, 2014L, 2016L, 2015L, 2016L ), EV.P1.GP = c( 0, 0.25, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.2105, 0.3636, 0.2368, 0.3333, 1, 0.3939, 0.1622, 0.1667 ), PP.P1.GP = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0702, 0, 0.0263, 0.1587, 0, 0.2121, 0, 0), P1.GP = c( 0, 0.25, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.3333, 0.3636, 0.2632, 0.4921, 1.5, 0.6364, 0.1622, 0.1667 ), EV.G = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 8L, 13L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 10L, 3L, 1L), EV.A1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L), EV.A2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L), EV.P1 = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 12L, 20L, 9L, 21L, 2L, 13L, 6L, 3L), PP.G = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L), PP.A1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), PP.A2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L), PP.P1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 10L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L), SH.G = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), SH.A1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), SH.A2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), EV.SHOTS = c(0L, 0L, 5L, 57L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 89L, 0L, 0L), EV.SH. = c(0, 0, 0, 1.75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11.24, 0, 0), PP.SHOTS = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 25L, 0L, 0L), PP.SH. = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0), SHOTS = c(0L, 0L, 5L, 57L, 3L, 93L, 0L, 38L, 0L, 0L, 118L, 53L, 37L), S. = c(0, 0, 0, 1.75, 0, 15.05, 0, 10.53, 0, 0, 13.56, 5.66, 2.7), TG = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 14L, 13L, 4L, 15L, 2L, 16L, 3L, 1L), TP1 = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 19L, 20L, 10L, 31L, 3L, 21L, 6L, 3L), TP = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 25L, 30L, 12L, 38L, 3L, 27L, 7L, 5L), TP.GP = c( 0, 0.25, 0, 0.16, 0, 0.4386, 0.5455, 0.3158, 0.6032, 1.5, 0.8182, 0.1892, 0.2778 ), Goals.P1 = c(0, 50, 0, 20, 0, 75, 65, 40, 48.39, 50, 80, 50, 33.33), EV.GF = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 28L, 0L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 26L, 14L, 7L), EV.GA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 32L, 0L, 21L, 0L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 12L, 9L), EV.GF. = c(0, 0, 100, 41.82, 100, 57.14, 0, 48.28, 0, 0, 59.09, 53.85, 43.75), EV.GF.Rel = c(0, 0, 46.34, 4.11, 55.56,-5.75, 0,-3.24, 0, 0,-5.87,-14.45,-16.91), OFF.EV.GF = c(0L, 0L, 22L, 92L, 4L, 100L, 0L, 51L, 0L, 0L, 76L, 84L, 37L), OFF.EV.GA = c(0L, 0L, 19L, 152L, 5L, 59L, 0L, 48L, 0L, 0L, 41L, 39L, 24L), eTOI.GP = c( NA, NA, 9.83, 14.3, 10.48, 14.06, NA, 12.73, NA, NA, 17.61, 11.77, 12.56 ), P1.e60 = c( NA, NA, 0, 0.4197, 0, 1.4222, NA, 1.2406, NA, NA, 2.1685, 0.827, 0.7965 ), DOB = c( "2001-06-28", "2001-06-28", "2001-09-21", "2001-09-21", "1998-04-14", "1998-04-14", "1993-11-14", "1993-11-14", "1996-12-14", "1996-12-14", "1996-12-14", "1996-12-14", "1996-12-14" ), AGE.SEPT.15 = c( 19.21, 18.21, 17.98, 18.98, 19.42, 20.42, 19.84, 20.84, 20.75, 17.75, 19.75, 18.75, 19.75 ), AGE.DEC.31 = c( 19.51, 18.51, 18.28, 19.28, 19.71, 20.71, 20.13, 21.13, 21.05, 18.05, 20.05, 19.05, 20.05 ), X. = c("-", "-", "27", "27", "25", "17", "-", "26", "-", "-", "8", "26", "26"), TEAM = c( "OLD", "Olds Grizzlys", "NIAG", "NIAG", "FGO", "FGO", "", "CLK", "SA", "", "ROU", "BU", "BU" ), HT = c( "5'10", "5'10", "-", "5'09", "-", "5'08", "-", "5'09", "6'03", "-", "-", "6'03", "6'03" ), SHOOTS = c("-", "-", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L"), GP = c(12L, 8L, 8L, 50L, 2L, 57L, 55L, 38L, 63L, 2L, 33L, 37L, 18L), DRAFT.YEAR = c( 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2016L, 2016L, 2012L, 2012L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L ), NHL.DRAFT = c( "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "COL (2015) - #39", "COL (2015) - #39", "COL (2015) - #39", "COL (2015) - #39", "COL (2015) - #39" ), DRAFT.TEAM = c( "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "COL", "COL", "COL", "COL", "COL" ), NHL.TEAM = c( "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "NJD", "NJD", "NJD", "NJD", "NJD" ) ), row.names = c(NA, 13L), class = "data.frame" )
```

I've tried to filter or select to no success. I figure its because i want to look for 3 years in a row and i don't know other features so do something like that. If possible my next question would be to look for players in those seasons who have increased in one stat each year(eg. moving from 50% EV.GF. in year 1 to 55% in year 2 and 56% in year 3) and filter to only look for those players who have increased in consecutive years.

Comment: A.J. Greer has two rows for 2016 with different values. How should this be handled?

Comment: Keeping both is ok. In the future i would like to filter out smaller games played samples and that would eliminate one of his rows

Answer (score 1):

You could filter players with 3 or more consecutive seasons using:

```r
library(tidyverse)

pick224_structure <- structure( list( LEAGUE = c( "AJHL", "AJHL", "OHL", "OHL", "USHL", "USHL", "USHL", "NCAA", "AHL", "USHL", "QMJHL", "NCAA", "NCAA" ), NAME = c( "A.J. Belanger", "A.J. Belanger", "A.J. Cook", "A.J. Cook", "A.J. Drobot", "A.J. Drobot", "A.J. Fossen", "A.J. Fossen", "A.J. Greer", "A.J. Greer", "A.J. Greer", "A.J. Greer", "A.J. Greer" ), DY... = c( "DY+1", "DY", "DY-1", "DY", "DY+1", "DY+2", "DY+1", "DY+2", "DY+2", "DY-1", "DY+1", "DY", "DY+1" ), PLAYER.ID = c( "44972/a.j.-belanger", "44972/a.j.-belanger", "46065/a.j.-cook", "46065/a.j.-cook", "39426/a.j.-drobot", "39426/a.j.-drobot", "30211/a.j.-fossen", "30211/a.j.-fossen", "36537/a.j.-greer", "36537/a.j.-greer", "36537/a.j.-greer", "36537/a.j.-greer", "36537/a.j.-greer" ), POS = c("F", "F", "D", "D", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"), SEASON = c( 2020L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2017L, 2018L, 2013L, 2014L, 2017L, 2014L, 2016L, 2015L, 2016L ), EV.P1.GP = c( 0, 0.25, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.2105, 0.3636, 0.2368, 0.3333, 1, 0.3939, 0.1622, 0.1667 ), PP.P1.GP = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0702, 0, 0.0263, 0.1587, 0, 0.2121, 0, 0), P1.GP = c( 0, 0.25, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.3333, 0.3636, 0.2632, 0.4921, 1.5, 0.6364, 0.1622, 0.1667 ), EV.G = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 8L, 13L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 10L, 3L, 1L), EV.A1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L), EV.A2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L), EV.P1 = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 12L, 20L, 9L, 21L, 2L, 13L, 6L, 3L), PP.G = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L), PP.A1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), PP.A2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L), PP.P1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 10L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L), SH.G = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), SH.A1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), SH.A2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), EV.SHOTS = c(0L, 0L, 5L, 57L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 89L, 0L, 0L), EV.SH. = c(0, 0, 0, 1.75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11.24, 0, 0), PP.SHOTS = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 25L, 0L, 0L), PP.SH. = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0), SHOTS = c(0L, 0L, 5L, 57L, 3L, 93L, 0L, 38L, 0L, 0L, 118L, 53L, 37L), S. = c(0, 0, 0, 1.75, 0, 15.05, 0, 10.53, 0, 0, 13.56, 5.66, 2.7), TG = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 14L, 13L, 4L, 15L, 2L, 16L, 3L, 1L), TP1 = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 19L, 20L, 10L, 31L, 3L, 21L, 6L, 3L), TP = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 25L, 30L, 12L, 38L, 3L, 27L, 7L, 5L), TP.GP = c( 0, 0.25, 0, 0.16, 0, 0.4386, 0.5455, 0.3158, 0.6032, 1.5, 0.8182, 0.1892, 0.2778 ), Goals.P1 = c(0, 50, 0, 20, 0, 75, 65, 40, 48.39, 50, 80, 50, 33.33), EV.GF = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 28L, 0L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 26L, 14L, 7L), EV.GA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 32L, 0L, 21L, 0L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 12L, 9L), EV.GF. = c(0, 0, 100, 41.82, 100, 57.14, 0, 48.28, 0, 0, 59.09, 53.85, 43.75), EV.GF.Rel = c(0, 0, 46.34, 4.11, 55.56,-5.75, 0,-3.24, 0, 0,-5.87,-14.45,-16.91), OFF.EV.GF = c(0L, 0L, 22L, 92L, 4L, 100L, 0L, 51L, 0L, 0L, 76L, 84L, 37L), OFF.EV.GA = c(0L, 0L, 19L, 152L, 5L, 59L, 0L, 48L, 0L, 0L, 41L, 39L, 24L), eTOI.GP = c( NA, NA, 9.83, 14.3, 10.48, 14.06, NA, 12.73, NA, NA, 17.61, 11.77, 12.56 ), P1.e60 = c( NA, NA, 0, 0.4197, 0, 1.4222, NA, 1.2406, NA, NA, 2.1685, 0.827, 0.7965 ), DOB = c( "2001-06-28", "2001-06-28", "2001-09-21", "2001-09-21", "1998-04-14", "1998-04-14", "1993-11-14", "1993-11-14", "1996-12-14", "1996-12-14", "1996-12-14", "1996-12-14", "1996-12-14" ), AGE.SEPT.15 = c( 19.21, 18.21, 17.98, 18.98, 19.42, 20.42, 19.84, 20.84, 20.75, 17.75, 19.75, 18.75, 19.7
                                      ), AGE.DEC.31 = c( 19.51, 18.51, 18.28, 19.28, 19.71, 20.71, 20.13, 21.13, 21.05, 18.05, 20.05, 19.05, 20.05 ), X. = c("-", "-", "27", "27", "25", "17", "-", "26", "-", "-", "8", "26", "26"), TEAM = c( "OLD", "Olds Grizzlys", "NIAG", "NIAG", "FGO", "FGO", "", "CLK", "SA", "", "ROU", "BU", "BU" ), HT = c( "5'10", "5'10", "-", "5'09", "-", "5'08", "-", "5'09", "6'03", "-", "-", "6'03", "6'03" ), SHOOTS = c("-", "-", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L"), GP = c(12L, 8L, 8L, 50L, 2L, 57L, 55L, 38L, 63L, 2L, 33L, 37L, 18L), DRAFT.YEAR = c( 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2016L, 2016L, 2012L, 2012L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L ), NHL.DRAFT = c( "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "COL (2015) - #39", "COL (2015) - #39", "COL (2015) - #39", "COL (2015) - #39", "COL (2015) - #39" ), DRAFT.TEAM = c( "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "COL", "COL", "COL", "COL", "COL" ), NHL.TEAM = c( "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "NJD", "NJD", "NJD", "NJD", "NJD" ) ), row.names = c(NA, 13L), class = "data.frame")
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
df <- pick224_structure %>%
  group_by(PLAYER.ID) %>%
  arrange(SEASON) %>%
  mutate(consecutive_season = cumsum(SEASON == lag(SEASON + 1,
                                                   default = first(SEASON)))) %>%
  filter(any(consecutive_season == 3))

df
#> # A tibble: 5 × 52
#> # Groups:   PLAYER.ID [1]
#>   LEAGUE NAME       DY... PLAYE…¹ POS   SEASON EV.P1…² PP.P1…³ P1.GP  EV.G EV.A1
#>   <chr>  <chr>      <chr> <chr>   <chr>  <int>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
#> 1 USHL   A.J. Greer DY-1  36537/… F       2014   1       0     1.5       1     1
#> 2 NCAA   A.J. Greer DY    36537/… F       2015   0.162   0     0.162     3     3
#> 3 QMJHL  A.J. Greer DY+1  36537/… F       2016   0.394   0.212 0.636    10     3
#> 4 NCAA   A.J. Greer DY+1  36537/… F       2016   0.167   0     0.167     1     2
#> 5 AHL    A.J. Greer DY+2  36537/… F       2017   0.333   0.159 0.492     9    12
#> # … with 41 more variables: EV.A2 <int>, EV.P1 <int>, PP.G <int>, PP.A1 <int>,
#> #   PP.A2 <int>, PP.P1 <int>, SH.G <int>, SH.A1 <int>, SH.A2 <int>,
#> #   EV.SHOTS <int>, EV.SH. <dbl>, PP.SHOTS <int>, PP.SH. <dbl>, SHOTS <int>,
#> #   S. <dbl>, TG <int>, TP1 <int>, TP <int>, TP.GP <dbl>, Goals.P1 <dbl>,
#> #   EV.GF <int>, EV.GA <int>, EV.GF. <dbl>, EV.GF.Rel <dbl>, OFF.EV.GF <int>,
#> #   OFF.EV.GA <int>, eTOI.GP <dbl>, P1.e60 <dbl>, DOB <chr>, AGE.SEPT.15 <dbl>,
#> #   AGE.DEC.31 <dbl>, X. <chr>, TEAM <chr>, HT <chr>, SHOOTS <chr>, GP <int>, …

# select a few columns of df to show that it worked as expected
df %>%
  select(LEAGUE, NAME, SEASON, consecutive_season)
#> Adding missing grouping variables: `PLAYER.ID`
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#> # Groups:   PLAYER.ID [1]
#>   PLAYER.ID        LEAGUE NAME       SEASON consecutive_season
#>   <chr>            <chr>  <chr>       <int>              <int>
#> 1 36537/a.j.-greer USHL   A.J. Greer   2014                  1
#> 2 36537/a.j.-greer NCAA   A.J. Greer   2015                  2
#> 3 36537/a.j.-greer QMJHL  A.J. Greer   2016                  3
#> 4 36537/a.j.-greer NCAA   A.J. Greer   2016                  3
#> 5 36537/a.j.-greer AHL    A.J. Greer   2017                  4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Not sure about your 'next question' ("look for players in those seasons who have increased in one stat each year") though, sorry.

Comment: Thanks so much! This returned what i was hoping from that data sample! My data set is much more expansive then just those players and leagues obviously so is their a function or something in R to collect those without typing them all in or typing in all the options for each column? Sorry if this is confusing or sounds like i don't know what i'm doing. Dipping my feet into R and definitely realizing i have lots to learn